# AutoCompleteTextView drop-down appears above the edit field instead of beneath

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView`, which drop-down appears above the view instead of below. Can someone help me and explain the reason of this? Can it be fixed without changing the layout too much?

Here is the part of my layout which includes mentioned `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearNewSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView16"
            android:layout_width="35dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0.0"
            android:textColor="#ffa500"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" = "
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText17"
            android:layout_width="45dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0.0" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="  x  "
            android:textColor="#00ff00"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/NewSearch"
            android:layout_width="190dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:dropDownHeight="120dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/NewList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/LinearNewSearch"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddNewSearch"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="#000080"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="8px"
            android:max="10"
            android:progress="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout80"
            android:layout_width="210dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:background="#25FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/List06"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've seen a suggestion to add `android:dropDownHeight="100dp"` to `AutoCompleteTextView` declaration, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [dropDownVerticalOffset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android%3adropDownVerticalOffset) attribute to AutoCompleteTextView in your xml:

```
  ...
         <AutoCompleteTextView
           android:id="@+id/NewSearch"
            android:layout_width="190dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    ...
                     android:dropDownVerticalOffset="50dp"
                    ...
                                             />
    ...
```