# Android AutoCompleteTextView suggestions appear half-off screen

Tags: android, layout

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` towards the side of my screen. This is the XML.

```
<AutoCompleteTextVie
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Location"/>
```

Here's the adapter I'm using.

```
locationsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, this.locations);
```

Unfortunately, the suggestions appear half-off the screen, so for example "Kitchen Table" appears as "Kitch".

Furthermore, when I move the button further left so that it stays on screen, the width of the drop-down is cut-off as the width of the button, which is smaller than many of the text options.

Any suggestions?

I'm using an HTC Sensation XL, don't know if this is device-dependent behaviour.

Related Question: [AutoCompleteTextView drop-down appears above the edit field instead of beneath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800537/autocompletetextview-drop-down-appears-above-the-edit-field-instead-of-beneath?rq=1)

Comment: I suppose the obvious answer is to move the button, which I've done, but it seems to me that it should be possible for the UI to display the drop-down menu on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys... I should've just looked up the docs!

```
android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="-30dp"
```

Possibly there are better ways of doing this... please let me know if you have a favourite.